# fit image inside div

Tags: css, html

I have a three div  block inside main div which is head,content and footer.
I have facing few problems which are:
(1) images not fiting inside div
  means i am try to find code for this situation:

```
<div style="height:10%">
  <img src="abc.jpg" height="100%">
</div>
```

and
(2) I have a div which height is `80%`,in this div i put three div their height is `20%, 60%, 20%`.the div whose height is `60%` has no data i write it for margin.(means first div `20% height` has a data then  `60% height  for space` then another div who has a data), so how to achive it?

(if possible please suggest without using `margin-up or bottom`

`HTML code:`

```
<div class="homebackground" style="height:100%; width:100%; background-image:url(../../stylesheets/images/Logo_with_Blu_bg.png); background-size:98% 88%">

<div class="bodyhead">
  <img src="../../stylesheets/images/user_male.png"/>
</div>

<div style="height:80%">

  <div style="width:100%">
     <div class="mainbodyup" align="right">
       <img src="../../stylesheets/images/phone.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="mainbodyup">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="mainbodyup">
        <img src="../../stylesheets/images/groupchat.png"/>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div style="height:60%; clear:both;" class="a">
    <div class="mainbodymid"></div>
    <div class="mainbodymid"></div>
    <div class="mainbodymid"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:100%">
     <div class="mainbodybot" align="right">
       <img src="../../stylesheets/images/recent.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="mainbodybot">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="mainbodybot">
        <img src="../../stylesheets/images/search.png"/>
     </div>
  </div>

</div> 

<div style="height:10%;">
</div>

</div>
```

`CSS:`

```
.bodyhead
{
    height:10%;
}
.bodyhead img
{
  width: 10%;
}
.mainbodyup
{
    height:20%;
    width:33%; 
    float:left;
}
.mainbodyup img
{
  width: 20%;
}
.mainbodymid
{
    width:33%; float:left; padding:0px;
}
.mainbodybot
{
    height:20%;
    width:33%; 
    float:left;
}
.mainbodybot img
{
  width: 20%;
}
.a:before
{
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.a:after
{
    clear:both;
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fit the entire image in the div . try using

```
style="background:url('image-url') no-repeat; background-size: 100%;"
```

for the `div` which contains the Image . Rather using the image object .

Comment: no it's not useful for me b'coz lateraly i used this images for click event and i don't want background images.your suggested thing i already used in my main div for background image.

Answer (score 1):

```
style="background:url('image-url') no-repeat; background-size: contain;"
```

Use this code.

Comment: in which place? and your answer is for my first question or second?

Comment: no..it's not what i try to found.i explain,i have a div whose class is `bodyhead` it's height is `10%` but image inside this div has height more than `10%` means it is not fit in div.

Comment: use style="background:url('image-url') no-repeat; background-size: cover;"

Answer (score 0):

add one css to your existing stysheet

```
html, body{
     height: 100%;
}
```